# JasperReports Server: How to export report as html file using url

Tags: java, html, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I need to export a report to a plain html file without the viewport of jasper reports.

If I do `&output=pdf` in url I get a pdf file, `&output=xls`, a xls file, but `&output=html` will show html inside a viewport of jasper reports. A want a html file too.

How can i achieve that? I am using the http api.

**From documentation**

*The following example executes the same report as shown in the previous section, but also passes 4012 as an input control parameter and exports to PDF instead of HTML:*

```
http://<host>:<port>/<context>/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&reportUnit=
/supermart/Details/CustomerDashboard&customerID=4012&output=pdf
```

---

[How to export JasperReport to HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547334/how-to-export-jasper-report-to-html)

Related question, however not helpful to me.

Comment: `If I do &output=pdf in url I get a pdf file` - About what application are you talking?

Comment: Are you talking about *JasperReports Server*?

Comment: @AlexK Yes, my data comes from a Jasper reports server.

Comment: And how did it turn out :D ?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use the REST API to export

http://localhost:8080/jasperserver-pro/rest_v2/reports/repo/path/to/report.html