# How to generate Jasper Report in HTML without writing file?

Tags: html, jasper-reports

The code below is generating the HTML report fine on a new browser window, but it is writing the HTML file on the app server.  Is there a way to generate an HTML report in Jasper without having to write the HTML file to the app server?
I can do it in PDF using JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(), but there's no such method for HTML.  Any ideas?

```
                 //For HTML file
                 String reportPath = JasperRunManager.runReportToHtmlFile(sourceFileName, parameters, conn);
                 File reportHtmlFile = new File(reportPath);
                 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(reportHtmlFile);
                 byte[] bytes =  new byte[(int)reportHtmlFile.length()];
                 fis.read(bytes);

                 response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline; ");
                 response.setContentType("text/html");
                 response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
                 servletOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                 servletOutputStream.flush();
                 servletOutputStream.close();
```

Comment: Use separately fillReport and export to stream
http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/27779612/jasper-report-export-html

Comment: Thanks @sanBez! The info in that link worked like a charm!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export JasperReports in HTML format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27779612/export-jasperreports-in-html-format)